# How to choose q threshold for pFDR?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

We are doing an activation map study and we want to control for false positives in multiple comparisons. Our map is around 5000 pixels. There's a lot of noise and variance so we see results that seem appropriate at p < 0.05 . About 10% of the map is significant activation.

We have run the Storey pFDR procedure to get q values, generating the pi-zero with the QVALUE GUI program in R. We don't get one pixel with q < 0.05 . A few start coming in at .14-.15, with a lot of values in the .20-.26 range, .26 probably being the mode of the distrib rounding to .00, then a reduction.

Now, Storey is clear ( in his PNAS article among others ) that the q value is a choice that doesn't have to match the p value for any particular reason. The PNAS supplmentary materials show some genetics values and the q values are often much much higher.

I can't see a great way to choose my q threshold. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of the threshold should NOT depend on the data. This is no different than the single hypothesis case of selecting a test's significance level so that a hypothesis is rejected. The type I error will naturally be 1.

The answer to your question is the following: Select a threshold based only on the proportion of false findings you are comfortable with. For example, if you can live with one in five findings being false? If so, set pFDR to 0.2. 
If you wish only to permit one in ten findings being false, set pFDR=0.1 and gather more data.

If your data has spatial structure, the noise process probably has spatial dependencies. Note that Storey's procedure assumes independently distributed test statistics. In case of dependence you should either consider the B-H procedure which permits PRDS type dependence. Otherwise, try and harness the spatial dependence into the problem to gain power (this will require rather high statistical expertise).